# Alter a months list dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I am stuck in a requirement.
I get two flags from the `database`, namely `lastMonthNumber` and `lastMonthName`, these can range from `1 to 12` and `January to December`.
Now I have a requirement such that if `lastMonthName="March"` and `lastMonthNumner=12`, then the parent `list` should be as below:

```
1, April
2, May
3, June
4, July
5, August
6, September
7, October
8, November
9, December
10, January
11, February
12, March
```

if `lastMonthName="April"` and `lastMonthNumber=6`, then the list should be:

```
7, November
8, December
9, January
10, February
11, March
12, April
```

This `lastMonthNumber` can range from `1 to 12` and `lastMonthName` too can range from `Jan to Dec`. The parent `list` needs to be dynamic.

If `lastMonthNumber=6` and `lastMonthName="April"`, then the `list` needs to have 6 elements with April as 12 and backtrack to have total 6 elements.

The parent `list` can be a `dictionary`, such as:

```
var monthsDictionary=new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

I am trying something as below, but not able to visualize further:

```
var monthsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var numbers = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
var months = new List<string> {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" };
 foreach (var month in months.Select())
     {
         if (month == lastMonthName)
            {

            }
      }
```

Please help. Pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: in your example for lastMonthName="April" and lastMonthNumber=6 how you identify what all value need to show/return?

Comment: The list needs to backtrack. If lastMonthNumber=6, then the parent list needs to have 6 elements, if lastMonthName=April, then it needs to backtrack starting from April having 6 elements. Hope it clears now.

Comment: so you mean if we can lastMonthName = 'Oct' and lastMonthNumber = 2, then result will be `11 - Sep, 12 - Oct`??

Comment: @DeepakSharma yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below fiddle.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/GYP2Go

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> GetRequiredResult(int lastMonthNumber, string lastMonthName)
{
    var indx =  months.IndexOf(lastMonthName);

    // here this list will have months in required order that ends with lastMonthName
    var revisedMonthList = new List<string>();
    revisedMonthList.AddRange(months.Skip(indx + 1).Take(12));
    revisedMonthList.AddRange(months.Take(indx + 1));

    // get count = lastMonthNumber element from last using index, and then convert them to dictionary.
    return revisedMonthList
        .Select((mn, index) => new {index, mn})
        .Where(c => c.index >= months.Count - lastMonthNumber)
        .ToDictionary(c=>c.index + 1, c=>c.mn); 
}
```

Comment: I'll try the code and will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't use a dictionary if the data is actually a sequence (List) and not expected to be accessed by the month number.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger, returned the dictionary from List because OP mentioned, return response can be dictionary of <int, string>

Answer (score 3):

Have a constant with month names

```
private readonly string[] monthNames = { "Januar" ..., "December" };
```

and an accessor method that is able to cycle the index:

```
private string GetMonthName(int index)
{
  if (index < 0) return monthNames[monthNames.Length - 1 - (index % monthNames.Length)];
  return monthNames[index % monthNames.Length];
}
```

Then create the list:

```
int indexOfLastMonthName = Array.IndexOf(monthNames, lastMonthName);

var parentData = Enumerable
  // Create as many items as last month number
  .Range(0, lastMonthNumber)

  // Create the list in reverse order, start on LastMonthName and 12,
  // then go back with every item
  .Select(x => new 
  { 
    Number = 12 - x, 
    Name = GetMonthName(indexOfLastMonthName - x)
  }

  // Turn it back
  .Reverse();
```

Then fill it to an appropriate data structure. e.g. like this:

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> parentList = parentData
  .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Number, x.Name)))
  .ToList();
```

---

If you prefer a classic solution (using the `GetMonthName` method from above):

```
int indexOfLastMonthName = Array.IndexOf(monthNames, lastMonthName);
List<Tuple<int, string>> parentList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

for(int i = 0; i < lastMonthNumber; i++)
{
  parentList.Add(
    Tuple.Create(
      12 - i, 
      GetMonthName(indexOfLastMonthName - i));
}

parentList.Reverse();
```

Comment: IndexOf doesn't take only 1 parameter.

Comment: Ok, it's an array. I should have used `Array.IndexOf` - Fixed.

Comment: I fixed a few minor things.

Comment: Thanks..I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this linq query

```
var months = new List<string> {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" };

var lastMonthNumber = ...;
var lastMonthName = ....;

var rows = months.Concat(months)
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(m => m != lastMonthName)
    .Take(lastMonthNumber)
    .Reverse()
    .Select((m, i) => new { id = i + 12 - lastMonthNumber + 1, m})
    .ToArray();
```

It duplicate a months list, reverse it and skip items until `lastMonthName` found. After that this code limit result items count to `lastMonthNumber` and reverse list back

Answer (score 0):

```
    var monthsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    var numbers = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    var months = new List<string> {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" };
int flag=0;
int items=12;
var numbersList = new List<int>();
var monthsList = new List<string>(); 
     foreach (var month in months)
         {
            if(flag==0){
             monthsList.Insert(items--,month);
             if (month == lastMonthName)
                {
                    flag=1;
                }
}
         else if(flag==1)
         {
           monthsList.add(month);
          }
          }
flag=0;
```

Comment: follow the same procedure for the number list and then you can add it to your dictionary object

Comment: I'll try the code and will let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
        var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new
        {
            I = i,
            M = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i)
        });

        //string lastMonthName = "March"; int lastMonthNumber = 12;
        //string lastMonthName = "April"; int lastMonthNumber = 6;
        var selMonthInt = months.Where(x => x.M == lastMonthName).Select(y => y.I).FirstOrDefault();
        int endCount = lastMonthNumber + selMonthInt;
        if (endCount >= 12) { endCount = selMonthInt; }

        var lst1 = months.Where(x => x.I > endCount).Select(z => z.M);
        var lst2 = months.Where(x => x.I <= selMonthInt).Select(z => z.M);
        var lst = lst1.Union(lst2).ToArray();

        var selMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, lastMonthNumber).Select(i => new { I = (13 - lastMonthNumber + i), M = lst[i] });
```